# Publishing an app only for ipod devices

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, app-store, ipod

I have to publish an app in the appstore but I want that only visible in ipods and ipads, NOT iphones. I saw apps, like whatsapp, are available for iphone and not for ipod and ipads. 
I couldn't find anything in the plist or in itunesconnect to configure this. Is there a way? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of your applications plist add `telephony` to your `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`(Required device capabilities) which needs to be of type dictionary. `telephony` needs to be set to NO to prohibit your application on devices that have telephony capabilities (iPhone).

Check out the [Declaring the Required Device Capabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW10) of the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html)

Comment: I have added the key with false value and now I'm not able to run the app on the iphone but i can on an ipad, so I guess apple will be this app unavailable for iphones. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Modify your Info.plist to include the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key. Pass it a dictionary with a `BOOL` `NO` for the `telephony` key.

Comment: I have added this: <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
 <dict>
  <key>telephony</key>
  <false/> . Is this what i need?
 </dict>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is correct and the same answer as Joe. I have to choose Joe because the answer was more descriptive. Sorry, this also happens to me most of time when answering :)